# How to $sum by index of sub-array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to $sum by index of sub-array

the code did not work.

```js
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$asks" },
  {
    $groups: {
      _id: 0,
      total: { $sum: { $arrayElemAt: ["$asks", 1] } },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
]);
```

[image]

Thank you so much

Comment: The number is in string type, try to convert it to double type before sum, `total: { $sum: { $toDouble: { $arrayElemAt: ["$asks", 1] } } },`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo in your code. Change $groups to $group
2. Convert the string value to a double value and then calculate sum
3. Based on your image, you should use index 0, not index 1

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZuT0DU7VgV8)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$asks"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 0,
      total: {
        $sum: {
          "$toDouble": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [ "$asks", 0 ]
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }
])
```